# HTML Strange looking chacteres in <select> element

Tags: html, character-encoding, char

One user of my system reported a strange-looking characters in a select-box. But it only appear for him. I have tested in every browser and none of them showed me this error.

The charset used in my html document is iso-8859-1

The user's browser is the lastest chrome (32), here is a print-screen of the error.

[image: Strange looking characters]

Comment: "The charset used in my html document is iso-8859-1" — What does the browser encoding settings say? Why are you using ISO 8859 1 in this century?

Comment: I know, i wasn't my choice. It was required by the client. I tried to convince to use UTF-8 without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is caused by font-face embedded fonts on select input...

try something like:

```
select, option { font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
```

Comment: Wow. It worked! I would never supposed that was a font problem. Thanks!